# Line bundles correspoding to a hyperplane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles, algebraic-vector-bundles

Assume we have a smooth projective variety $X$ over a field and a hyperplane section $H$ on it. For each Weil divisor on $X$ you can construct a line bundle on $X$. For $H$ this line bundle which is denoted by $O(H)$ will be given as a sheaf by $O(H)(U)=\{f\in K| f+H\geq 0$ on $U \}$. So by this definition it is given as a sub sheaf of the constant sheaf given by $K$ which is the function field of $X$. What strikes me as strange is that you can give similar definitions for all $O(nH)$ and $O$ which is the trivial line bundle and by this definition it looks like that $O(nH)$ is a subsheaf of $O(mH)$ for $n<m$. Specially $O$ is a subsheaf of $O(H)$. Is this correct? or what exactly am I missing?

Comment: Line bundles are associated to Cartier divisors, not Weil divisors.  But given that an inclusion of O as a subsheaf of O(H) is given by a section of O(H).

Comment: @aginensky In the smooth case I believe there is an equivalence of Cartier and Weil divisors.

Comment: Yes, but why not use the correct formulation ?  The fact is that line bundles are associated to Cartier divisors, not Weil divisors.  It is a fact that for smooth they are the same.  Once you do that your question is true without smooth.